# Package Microsoft.CSharp 4.5.0 not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 Error Message

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to run a ASP.NET Core 2.0 app. However when I click on run in IDE (to build the app) I get this error:

> Controller.csproj: [NU1202] Package Microsoft.CSharp 4.5.0 is not
>   compatible  with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package
>   Microsoft.CSharp 4.5.0 does not support any target frameworks.
>
> Controller.csproj: [NU1202] Package System.Security.Principal 4.3.0 is
>   not  compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package
>   System.Security.Principal 4.3.0 does not support any target
>   frameworks.

Thank you inadvance.

Comment: You tried to add a Full Framework package to a .NET Core application.

Comment: Please post your `csproj` file, especially the `PackageReference` elements. Post the *text*, not a screenshot of the text

Comment: @Panagiotis, Here it is:                                                                                                 `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> <PropertyGroup> <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework> </PropertyGroup> <ItemGroup> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" /> </ItemGroup> </Project> `

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an old version of Visual Studio. To create a net core 2.1 application you need at least Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7 or if you cannot access this version then switch to Visual Studio Code that is free.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't think the issue has to do with Visual Studio version. I have the latest version. In fact, I have been using Rider (from JetBrains) to code C#, which is updated but still brings up the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure you have no project targeting .the NET Framework rather than .NET Core or .NET Standard? In Rider you right click in each project node and select properties.

Answer (score 0):

Can you delete the reference to `Package System.Security.Principal 4.3.0` and in the package manager do: 
`Install-Package System.Security.Principal.Windows -Version 4.6.0-preview.18571.3`

`Package System.Security.Principal 4.3.0` requires .NET Framework 4.5 and is not compatible with .NET Core as the error says.

Comment: Unfortunately, I unable to find the package locate the package. I think you are right; there are missing packages. I don't understand how dependencies are managed in ASP.NET. The main package is not detected I have installed a new project but the same issue occurs.

Comment: @Deshola Open your csproj and check the `PackageReference` elements. You added a Full Framework package to your project. BTW if you target .NET Core 2.1 shouldn't you use the same version of ASP.NET Core ?

Comment: I had the same issues before. Please check this URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools. Download nuget.exe and put it in C:\Windows. open a console and  in the project folder use nuget restore to see if it solves the problem. Also please check that you have dotnet SDK version is 2.1.500. In macOS nuget is included with the SDK.

Comment: Thank you. But I did not even modify the project to begin with. `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
`

Comment: @Juanjo, thank you. Yes, I am running 2.1.6. I will try your example and update you.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this issue by creating a new solution and pointing to the right variables (framework and others). Thank you so much for your contribution.